# How to set defaults in Jplayer

Tags: jquery, html, jplayer

I can't figure out how to set `nativeSupport` to `false` from the page where the JPlayer is.

The code that i am trying to change is this:

```
        $.jPlayer.defaults = {
    cssPrefix: "jqjp",
    swfPath: "js",
    volume: 80,
    oggSupport: false,
    nativeSupport: true,  //I want to change this one to false
    preload: 'none',
    customCssIds: false,
    graphicsFix: true,
    errorAlerts: false,
    warningAlerts: false,
    position: "absolute",
    width: "0",
    height: "0",
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    quality: "high",
    bgcolor: "#ffffff"
};
```

I have tried this with no luck:

```
    $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("option", "nativeSupport", "false");
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well since no one posted.

Instead of using some javascript function for Jplayer. I instead just used php to echo out two different javascript files. One had `nativeSupport = false`, and the other `true`.

I know this isn't the preferred method, but it works. Here is the code I used:

```
    <?php
        if($somthing == $somthingelse) {
           echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="jPlayer/js/jquery.jplayer.nativefalse.js"></script>';
        } else{
           echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="jPlayer/js/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>';
        }
    ?>
```